# Build JAR for multiple versions of API

Tags: java, git

I have a Repository that is built against different versions of the API for a software. (Java Class Library that generates a jar at the end)

The build process was working when the API did not change (atleast for the classes that i was using)

The recent version of the API changed a class and this has led to the build failing (master branch) for only this version.

To solve this, I created a branch from the master and changed the code to suit the API.  now 2 branches are being built, master for all versions other than the newest API and one branch that is only for the latest API.

Is this the correct way to go about this or is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use the version of the api compatible with your repo in master and ignore the latest releases?

Comment: Do one of the following:
1. Keep on using the API version compatible with your code
2. Upgrade the rest of the project to use the latest API
3. Selectively use the old API for the incompatible part of your code, and use the latest one for the rest. (Not recommended; and may not be possible either based on whether you've written the API client library yourself or not)

Comment: I would consider moving away from that API if at all possible.  APIs are supposed to be stable.  How many more times will you need to chase after API changes in the future, instead of concentrating on your own development work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to keep two repos one for old and one for new.